# facebook search api

Tags: search, facebook

Does anyone know if the facebook search api http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#search allow us to perform OR queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try "keyword1 | keyword2" as search query string.
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Smart.fm+%7C+iKnow&type=post

Comment: I don't think it is working anymore. wondering if you tried it recently?

Answer (score 0):

var searchQueryString = 'search?q=' + query + '&type=' + type
        FB.api('/' + searchQueryString, function (response) {

```
    });
```

The above one is the example of how you can search from facebook.
query -- the search keyword

type -- type of the search(eg. 'post' gives you the posts with that keyword)

before using the above query, you need to add the reference of the conncet.js.

here is the code for the same.

http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js

Add this script in your html before the function

Mark as answer if this helps you, so that the other people will not have any trouble in identifying what they want.

Hope this helps
happy coiding

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, OR queries is not possible anymore.